# Python Gurobi : Iteration with a threshold on gap

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gurobi

I try to solve a MIP for planification over several periods by solving the same model over several ierations. How can i use 'callback' to go to next iteration when threshold of the gap is reached or the resolution takes some time without improvement ?
Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, it's easier to use restarts with multiple termination criteria; for details, see [Gurobi FAQ 13](http://www.gurobi.com/support/faqs).  If you must use a callback, look at the callback code in the examples subdirectory.